# How to calculate CAPM variables in Julia?

Tags: julia, finance

In Python, using stats of scipy package, variables `beta`, `alpha`, `r`, `p`, `std_err` of CAPM can be calculated as follows:

```
beta, alpha, r_value, pvalue, std_err = stats.linregress(stock_rtn_arr, mkt_rtn_arr)
```

Please guide me in calculating the above variables in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking to run a simple OLS model, which in Julia can be fit using the `GLM` package:

```
julia> using GLM, DataFrame

julia> mkt_rtn_arr = randn(500); stock_rtn_arr = 0.5*mkt_rtn_arr .+ rand();

julia> df = DataFrame(mkt_rtn = mkt_rtn_arr, stock_rtn = stock_rtn_arr);

julia> linear_model = lm(@formula(stock_rtn ~ mkt_rtn), df)
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

stock_rtn ~ 1 + mkt_rtn

Coefficients:
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
             Estimate   Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  0.616791  7.80308e-18  7.90446e16    <1e-99   0.616791   0.616791
mkt_rtn      0.5       7.78767e-18  6.42041e16    <1e-99   0.5        0.5
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

You can then extract the parameters of interest from the `linear_model`:

```
julia> β = coef(linear_model)[2]
0.4999999999999999

julia> α = coef(linear_model)[1]
0.6167912017573035

julia> r_value = r2(linear_model)
1.0

julia> pvalues = coeftable(linear_model).cols[4]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0

julia> stderror(linear_model)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 7.803081577574428e-18
 7.787667394841443e-18
```

Note that I have used the [`@formula`](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/latest/api/#StatsModels.@formula) API to run the regression, which requires putting your data into a `DataFrame` and is in my opinion the preferred way of estimating the linear model in GLM, as it allows for much more flexibility in specifying the model. Alternatively you could have called `lm(X, y)` directly on an array for your `X` variable and the `y` variable:

```
julia> lm([ones(length(mkt_rtn_arr)) mkt_rtn_arr], stock_rtn_arr)
LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}}:

Coefficients:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    Estimate   Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x1  0.616791  7.80308e-18  7.90446e16    <1e-99   0.616791   0.616791
x2  0.5       7.78767e-18  6.42041e16    <1e-99   0.5        0.5
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Note that here I have appended a column of ones to the market return array to estimate the model with an intercept, which the `@formula` macro will do automatically (similar to the way it's done in R).

Comment: May I request for a few improved models of CAPM

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?